# using helper_method AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my **application controller** I have the following code:

```
helper_method :current_user


def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user]) if session[:user] 
end
```

I would like to use the "current_user" method in a model.  According to the rails API the helper method can be accessed at "AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods".
See link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html

When I add this to my model I get a method not found error:

```
include AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods
```

Am I missing something in how to include these helper methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't and you shouldn't.

The model doesn't have (and should not have) any visibility of the view and the controller. The clear separation is one of the key principle of the MVC pattern.

If you want a method in your model to have access to the current user, then pass the user when invoking the method.

For instance, assuming you want to pass the user on the Post creation, define a custom method

```
class Post
  def do_something_with_user(user)
    # ...
  end  
end
```

and call it from the controller

```
def action
  Post.find(...).do_something_with_user(current_user)
end
```

There are possible workarounds, such as storing the current user into the current thread or in a global variable, but this is gonna break the rules (and you should not break the rules).

Comment: Right.  I figured that it was probably not the best idea, but I know its possible to add helpers into your model by including ActionView::Helpers.  See http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views?view=comments.  Thank you!+